# Signal Raised event stops my copy process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, signals

Here i have one sample code for signal Handling and copy process.
Here i want to call one timer using signal action, for every second.
Its working fine here but when i add my copy process code in between start and stop timer function that time my copy process will be killed when first time signal raised means after 1 second.

Here i tried with these `SIGRTMAX ,SIGUSR1, SIGALRM` signals but they all give same results.

Why my copy process stops when signal raised.?

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIGTIMER SIGRTMAX


timer_t KeepAliveTimerId;



void stopKeepAlive()
{
    if(KeepAliveTimerId != NULL)
    {
        timer_delete(KeepAliveTimerId);
        printf("timer delete\n");

    }
}

void  signalHandler(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    if (signo == SIGTIMER)
    {
        printf("Signal Raised\n");
    }
}

int startKeepAlive()
{
    struct sigevent sigev; //signal event struct
    struct itimerspec itval;
    struct itimerspec oitval;
    struct sigaction sigact;


    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigact.sa_sigaction = signalHandler;

    // set up sigaction to catch signal
    if (sigaction(SIGTIMER, &sigact, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("time_settime error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Create the POSIX timer to generate signo
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev.sigev_signo = SIGTIMER;
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_int = 2;

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &KeepAliveTimerId) == 0)
     {
        itval.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        itval.it_value.tv_nsec = 0L;
        itval.it_interval.tv_sec = itval.it_value.tv_sec;
        itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = itval.it_value.tv_nsec;

        if (timer_settime(KeepAliveTimerId, 0, &itval, &oitval) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error in set time \n");
            return -2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error in creating timer \n");
        return -3;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int result; 
    // Start Timer
    startKeepAlive();

    result = system("cp /mnt/bct/package.QuipC /Download/ 2>&1");
    if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("result is %d\n",result);
        //stop timer
        stopKeepAlive();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    printf("result is %d\n",result);
    // Stop Timer
    stopKeepAlive();
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: You should not call printf() and friends from a signal handler. Never.

Comment: @wildplasser Here i am asking different things and are u doing here code review??

Comment: @wildplasser I put printf for debugging only

Comment: I read like a code reviewer. Once I see an error like this, I stop scanning. I did not even read the full question. Even for debugging it is wrong. The program cannot be correct, whatever other errors are lurking in there.

Comment: @wildplasser Thats Good Thing but here i am in different trouble dats why i am used printf for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You use real-time signals, from http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html:

> ...
> The default action for an unhandled real-time signal is to terminate
> the receiving process ...

So it seems that calling system(...) somehow affects your signal handler. I would suggest (as  wildplasser already mentioned) getting rid of obvious mistake (printf in signal handler). Under above link you also have nice list of functions that can be used in signal handler (paragraph Async-signal-safe functions). After you do it please tell us if it made any difference.

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer but here i already handled my signal action. Why its signal handler first call termincates my copy process

Comment: Try running it through strace. Maybe system() does not clear the sigmask for the child process after all. It does fiddle with the parent's sigmask per the man page SIGCHLD, SIGINT and SIGQUIT ARE reset for the parent.

Comment: @wildplasser i didnt get you..What are u telling? please can u explain me in detail. If if i use peopn instead of system command that also not working.

Comment: system() does a lot of things: setting sigmask, fork, exec a shell, .... Read the manpage. Please be more precise. "not working" is not very descriptive. Does it crash? Does it hang? Does it return immediately?

Comment: It is return immediately? when ever first time signal raised then its return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure I added this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
int zprintf(char *fmt, ...);
int zprintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
int rc;
char buff[100];
va_list aaa;

va_start(aaa, fmt);
rc = sprintf(buff, fmt, aaa);
va_end(aaa);

rc = write(2, buff, rc);
return rc;
}
```

And replaced the signal handler by:

```
void  signalHandler(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    if (signo == SIGTIMER)
    {
        zprintf("Signal Raised\n");
    }
    else
    {
        zprintf("Signal %d Raised\n", signo);
    }
}
```

... and replaced the system() string like:

```
result = system("cp ../wakker/megahal-9.1.1.dld/tele/megahal.brn /tmp/ 2>&1");
```

And it worked:

```
$ ./a.out
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
result is 0
timer delete
```

Could be coincidence. (But Undefined Behavior is also coincidence!)

Comment: But u checked on cross platform devices. i have no issue on my desktop computer. which have x86-64 bit ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this code (trivial variation on the original — added explicit `void` argument lists, and `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` to get the `timer_t` declarations, simplified the signal handler, and linked and tested on Linux (RHEL 5) with `-lrt` because Mac OS X doesn't have `timer_t` in any header under `/usr/include` — with a simpler command to execute (echo, sleep, echo), and got the plausible looking output:

```
Started
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Signal Raised
Done
result is 0
timer delete
```

I infer from this that the timing signals do not affect the command run by `system()`, as indeed they should not.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O3 -std=c99 sau.c -o sau -lrt
```

The `-std=c99` option probably accounts for me needing to specify `_XOPEN_SOURCE`.  If I could be bothered to compile with `-std=gnu99`, it probably would not be needed.

#### Code

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIGTIMER SIGRTMAX

timer_t KeepAliveTimerId;

void stopKeepAlive(void)
{
    if(KeepAliveTimerId != NULL)
    {
        timer_delete(KeepAliveTimerId);
        printf("timer delete\n");
    }
}

void  signalHandler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGTIMER)
    {
        printf("Signal Raised\n");
    }
}

int startKeepAlive(void)
{
    struct sigevent sigev; //signal event struct
    struct itimerspec itval;
    struct itimerspec oitval;
    struct sigaction sigact;

    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigact.sa_handler = signalHandler;

    // set up sigaction to catch signal
    if (sigaction(SIGTIMER, &sigact, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("time_settime error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Create the POSIX timer to generate signo
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev.sigev_signo = SIGTIMER;
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_int = 2;

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &KeepAliveTimerId) == 0)
     {
        itval.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        itval.it_value.tv_nsec = 0L;
        itval.it_interval.tv_sec = itval.it_value.tv_sec;
        itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = itval.it_value.tv_nsec;

        if (timer_settime(KeepAliveTimerId, 0, &itval, &oitval) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error in set time \n");
            return -2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error in creating timer \n");
        return -3;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int result; 
    // Start Timer
    startKeepAlive();

    result = system("echo Started; sleep 10; echo Done");
    if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("result is %d\n",result);
        //stop timer
        stopKeepAlive();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    printf("result is %d\n",result);
    // Stop Timer
    stopKeepAlive();
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: I don't know; I really didn't change much at all.  I just made sure it compiled cleanly without warnings under the command line shown.  AFAICT, I made no substantive changes, so I don't know why you were seeing your copy process stop unexpectedly when my command line did not.  Maybe the issue is that because of the shell metacharacters (semi-colons), `system()` ran a real shell and the shell insulated the commands it ran, but your copy command was treated differently and executed directly (though it has the `2>&1` shell metacharacters in it, so this is probably clutching at straws).